# Java memory space overlap?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a problem of adding elements into an ArrayList. Each time I do the 'add', the entire array content is replaced with the current element value. I end up with eg. 10 repeated element duplicates.

The classes are set up as follows:

```
public class BradfordReport {
    EmployeeRow _empRow = new EmployeeRow();
    ArrayList<EmployeeRow> _bradfordData = new ArrayList<EmployeeRow>();

    public void Run() {
       // processing to setup Employee row variables
       for (int x=0; x<10; x++) {
           // This next line in debug IS ADJUSTING THE ARRAYLIST DATA!!
           _empRow.EmpNum = x; // etc for other variable in EmployeeRow
           _bradfordData.add(er);
       }
    }
    // THE RESULT IN _bradfordData is 10 elements, all with EmpNum = 10!
 }

public class EmployeeRow {
    int EmpNum;
    string EmpNm; // etc.
 }
```

Am I getting Java memory allocation confused here? It appears that EmployeeRow variable and the ArrayList are sharing the same memory space - very peculiar. Thanks guys

Comment: The important thing is, do you **understand** what went wrong and why? This is a classic OO (Object-Oriented) beginners mistake, so if you struggle to know why, let us know and we can explain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding the same instance of the `EmployeeRow` class to the arraylist. Try something like:

```
public class BradfordReport {
    EmployeeRow _empRow = new EmployeeRow();
    ArrayList<EmployeeRow> _bradfordData = new ArrayList<EmployeeRow>();

    public void Run() {
       // processing to setup Employee row variables
       for (int x=0; x<10; x++) {
           // create a NEW INSTANCE of an EmployeeRow
           _empRow = new EmployeeRow();
           _empRow.EmpNum = x; // etc for other variable in EmployeeRow
           _bradfordData.add(_empRow);
       }
    }
    // THE RESULT IN _bradfordData is 10 elements, all with EmpNum = 10!
}

public class EmployeeRow {
    int EmpNum;
    string EmpNm; // etc.
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Nico, dacwe, pst and Rig...made the change to include a 'new' in the loop and it all works fine. By the way, same question was asked at 4161827.  Thanks again

Comment: @Pete855217 - No problems dude, we are here to help :)

Answer (score 2):

**Only *one* EmployeeRow object is every created.**

Then it is modified. "It" being "the same object". If a *new* object is desired, then create a *new* object :)

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Yes when you do

```
 _empRow.EmpNum = x;
```

you are changing the objects internal variable. You need to construct a new object each time. Inside the loop do something like this:

```
EmployeeRow _empRow = new EmployeeRow();
 _empRow.EmpNum = x; 
 _bradfordData.add(_empRow);
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't creating new rows so every element is the same and since the loop ends at ten the last object has a value of ten.

```
public class BradfordReport {
EmployeeRow _empRow = new EmployeeRow();
ArrayList<EmployeeRow> _bradfordData = new ArrayList<EmployeeRow>();

public void Run() {
   // processing to setup Employee row variables
   for (int x=0; x<10; x++) {
       // This next line in debug IS ADJUSTING THE ARRAYLIST DATA!!
       _empRow = new EmployeeRow();
       _empRow.EmpNum = x; // etc for other variable in EmployeeRow
       _bradfordData.add(er);
   }
 }
 // THE RESULT IN _bradfordData is 10 elements, all with EmpNum = 10!
}
```